# Chaining 4 unix commands together and breaking the command to additional lines

Tags: shell, unix

I used to run a simple line in my .sh file, such as:

```
python myFileA.py && python myFileB.py
```

but i wanted to do it with 4 files.  At first, i was thinking yea this is easy.

```
python myFileA.py && python myFileB.py && python myFileC.py && python myFileD.py
```

but in actuality, the commands are way more complex than this.  I wanted to know if for cleanliness sake i can continue it to the next line with the `_` character.

```
python myFileA.py && _ 
python myFileB.py && _ 
python myFileC.py && _ 
python myFileD.py
```

Is this the right character/design i should be using?

You might be thinking, *Why dont you just put them sequentially on seperate lines*, but the answer to that is that the files are async, so when B starts, it will fail because A is not complete.  I dont know if this adds much complexity, but it seems when i was doing the simple 2 command way, it was working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of underscore you need to use `\` here for continuation:

```
python myFileA.py && \
python myFileB.py && \ 
python myFileC.py && \ 
python myFileD.py
```

However since you have `&&` you don't really need to use `\` and can just skip it:

```
python myFileA.py &&
python myFileB.py &&
python myFileC.py &&
python myFileD.py
```

Comment: I forget what language uses the underscore.  In that case, cool! Thanks a lot for the assist.  I knew it was one of those special characters.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui: I added it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

With bash you don't need *any* continuation character following `&&`, `||`, `|`

```
python myFileA.py &&
python myFileB.py &&
python myFileC.py &&
python myFileD.py
```